# Plesk12のMySQLで外部からデータベースにアクセスできない

Tags: mysql

Plesk 12を利用しています。MySQLデータベースへの外部サーバからのリモートアクセスを試そうとしたところ、接続ができず失敗してしまいます。

「任意のホストの接続を許可する」にしても、変化がありませんでした。
ログを読んでも、特に関係するものが残っていませんでした。

Comment: これを [How do I enable remote access to MySQL database server?](http://kb.parallels.com/en/1134) 参考にしてみてはいかかでしょうか。

Comment: エラーメッセージなどの詳細情報を載せると回答者の参考になると思います。

Comment: @heliac2001
こちらの方法も試していたのですが、うまく動作しなかったため諦めていました。データベースを囲む`○○○\_△△△△`が''と思って入力していたようで、設定できていなかったようです。
おかげでしっかりとアクセスできるようになりました。

ありがとうございました！

Comment: @tomute
エラーメッセージは、リモートアクセスするサーバには、接続できない旨のみのエラーメッセージが、リモートアクセスされるサーバには、何も残っていませんでした。
問題も解決し、原因も分かったのでよかったです。回答いただきありがとうございました！

Comment: @user6127 自己解決できたようで何よりです。解決策を回答として書いて、チェックマークをつけておいて頂けると、本質問がクローズしている事が他の方にわかりやすくなります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

データベースを囲む`○○○\_△△△△`が'○○○\_△△△△'と思って入力していたようで、設定できていなかったようです。

---

<sup>この投稿は @user6127 さんの[コメント](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/3184/plesk12%e3%81%aemysql%e3%81%a7%e5%a4%96%e9%83%a8%e3%81%8b%e3%82%89%e3%83%87%e3%83%bc%e3%82%bf%e3%83%99%e3%83%bc%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ab%e3%82%a2%e3%82%af%e3%82%bb%e3%82%b9%e3%81%a7%e3%81%8d%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84#comment1793_3184)などを元に編集し、[コミュニティWiki](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1583)として投稿しました。</sup>